# How have I got two identical Amazon Prime Video apps on my phone?

Tags: iphone, applications

I recently clicked a link which took me to the App Store to download the Amazon Prime Video app. This was confusing to me because I already have that app. I downloaded it anyway, and now I have two identical (looking) apps on my phone? How is this possible? I have an iPhone SE.

[image]

Comment: One of them is probably a bookmark from safari added by the "Add the Home Screen" option.

Comment: Why did this happen? I dunno. You can always delete them both and re-download the most current version.

Comment: It’s not a bookmark. They are both the app. And yes, I can delete them both and reinstall, but I’d like to know how this happened.

Comment: To the downvoter: it would be useful to know why you downvoted.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted....

Comment: In Settings, when you scroll down to the section where installed apps are listed, do you see Prime Video twice? Do you install apps using more than one Apple ID?

Comment: @jaume I don't use more than one apple ID, no. But when I look in settings (good idea) I can see that two are installed, and they are different versions (5.6.1 and 6.0). Not sure why these are considered different apps, though. Something to do with the major version upgrade, perhaps?   No differences in the settings except 6.0 does not have the option to turn off Mobile Data usage. Version history on [this](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/amazon-prime-video/id454468674?mt=8) page doesn't seem to help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can answer this one for you. Amazon are trying to transfer everybody to a new app. The one you linked to is the old one. Search the app store and you'll find the new one (at V6.4 vs 6.1 for the old).
A while back Amazon sent a push message with a link telling everyone to update. You probably did and didn't delete the old one.
What the difference is at this point in time between the two? Probably nothing. That might change though.

Comment: It would seem from my own research that something called a Bundle Id is what identifies an app, and you can't have two apps with the same bundle ID. So the _difference_ between the two is, I'm guessing, the bundle Id. It seems that Amazon have "updated" their app simply by publishing an entirely new one (with a new bundle Id). Quite why they would do that is beyond me, but thanks for the info.

Comment: Exactly right. They issued a new app and asked everybody to download that instead. It could be something to do with inheriting an Apple developer account from Love Film (the company in the UK that they bought and replaced the app of). So if centralising all their apps to a single developer account, maybe they had to do that. I don't know, but what you described is correct. I reckon just update all your apps and delete the version that's 6.1 instead of 6.4 and leave Amazon's old app to its merry ways. Already taken up too much headspace for us both! :)

Comment: Yep, makes sense. Nice to know what’s going on though! Cheers.